# How to use enum with input in MQL5?

Tags: input, enums, mql5

I created my `enum`:

```
#property script_show_inputs

enum MYENUM
{
    first,
    second
};

input MYENUM response;

int OnInit()
{
    if (response == first)
    {
        printf("first");
    }

    if (response == second)
    {
        printf("second");
    }
}
```

It looks working before init, you can click on drop down and choose value. But when `OnInit()` starts it always default "first" value with no matter which was chosen.

How to use `enum` with input?

Comment: `input MYENUM response=first;` same as regular inputs - you have to explicitly declare default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where MQL4/5 has a bit of introspection. The variable name for the `input` will be replaced (in the input window) by a single line comment following it's declaration, and the same goes for enum fields.

```
#property script_show_inputs

enum MYENUM
{
    first, //First choice
    second //Second choice
};

input MYENUM response = first; //Which choice?

int OnInit()
{
    if (response == first)
        printf("first");
    else if (response == second)
        printf("second");
}
```

The input window will read `Which choice? | First choice` instead of `response | first`